# How to construct a ring $ R$ such that $(Spec(R), \tau)$ is not a Sequential Space where $\tau$ is the Zariski Topology on $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, zariski-topology

How to construct a ring $ R$ such that $(Spec(R), \tau)$ is not a Sequential Space where $\tau$ is the Zariski Topology  on Spec(R).

I've just learned about Zariski topology so I really don't have any idea about to solve this problem Please help!

**Added:** Actually I'm trying to find a function $f : X \to Y$ which is sequential continuous but not Continuous.For this problem I've already proved that such $f$ will exist only if $X$ is a Sequential Space,also I was able to construct example by taking $ X= \omega +1$ with order topology.But I was wondering if there is a ring $R$ for which $Spec(R)$ with Zariski topology is not sequential space.

Comment: Something is missing from this post: if you have just learned about the Zariski topology, how did you think up the problem in the first place? On this site, we look for more than just the statement of a problem - we look for the background, the otivation, and what you have attempted so far. You can edit the post to include additional information.

Comment: @Carl:I've added some lines,I apologize for my mistake.Best Regards,